# Split de una consulta

Tags: java, webservice, netbeans

Tengo una consulta desde java un web services en c#, donde busco todos los datos de determinado id de una tabla y lo devuelve por medio de una cadena aun jtextfield, pero quisiera que en lugar de mostrarme toda la cadena en un solo jtextfield me  mostrara los datos por separado.

Lo intenté con el siguiente código, pero al presionar el botón no pasa nada y tampoco me marca errores.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int id=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    String cadena=consultaAlumno(id);
    String[] parts = cadena.split("-");
    String  jTextField2=parts[0];
    String  jTextField3=parts[1];
    String  jTextField4=parts[2];
    String  jTextField5=parts[3];
    String  jComboBox1=parts[4];
}
```

Comment: puedes poner que contiene cadena antes de hacer el split?

Comment: 34-nombre-apellido-edad-dirección-telefono-sexo esos datos son los que contiene la cadena asi la manda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo haces en c#, al hacerlo así no da ningún problema, eso si, lo almacenas en Strings, no vas a ver visualmente ningún cambio en la parte gráfica:

```
String cadena="34-nombre-apellido-edad-dirección-telefono-sexo";
String[] parts = cadena.Split('-');
String  jTextField2=parts[0];  //Se mete 34
String  jTextField3=parts[1];  //Se mete nombre
String  jTextField4=parts[2];  //Se mete apellido
String  jTextField5=parts[3];  //Se mete edad
String  jComboBox1=parts[4];   //Se mete direccion
```

Si lo haces en java:

```
String cadena="34-nombre-apellido-edad-dirección-telefono-sexo";
String[] parts = cadena.split("-");
String  jTextField2=parts[0];
String  jTextField3=parts[1];
String  jTextField4=parts[2];
String  jTextField5=parts[3];
String  jComboBox1=parts[4];
```

Esto funciona en java pero, como he dicho antes, ten en cuenta que lo estás metiendo en Strings, no en objetos de tipo Combobox ni TextField. Si pones un punto de interrupción verás que si que te divide la cadena.

Comment: y para meterlos en los textfield y el combo box como seria?

Comment: Tienes que crear objetos del tipo que quieras pero no Strings. Crea los jTexField así: JTextField campo 1 = new JTextField(); y ahora haces campo1.setText("la cadena que quieras")

Comment: Compañero siento molestarte pero creo los jtexfield y para hacer el split?

Comment: el split como te lo he puesto funciona, yo le he pasado la cadena desde código y lo hace sin problema. Lo he puesto en c# y en java, fíjate que en c# es con comilla simple y Split con mayúsculas y en jaca split es con minúsculas y comillas dobles

Answer (score 0):

Para añadir texto a un textfield tienes que usar `.setText()`

```
jTextField2.setText(parts[0]);
jTextField3.setText(parts[1]);
jTextField4.setText(parts[2]);
jTextField5.setText(parts[3]);
```

Comment: asi va?, me sale un error que falta un ; pero no veo donde

Comment: Sin ver tu código no puedo saber donde te falta un `;`

Comment: private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int id=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        String cadena=consultaAlumno(id);
        String[] parts = cadena.split("-");
        
          String  jTextField2.setText(parts[0]);
String  jTextField3.setText(parts[1]);
String  jTextField4.setText(parts[2]);
String  jTextField5.setText(parts[3]);
       
    }

Comment: jTextField2,3,4,5 son Strings aunque le haya dado el nombre de un objeto (cosa bastante mal hecha), así que no hay que utilizar el método setText, es más, un String no tiene ese método.

Comment: Si son strings, entonces normal que no se le rellenen los campos :(

Comment: claro, fíjate que aunque les ponga ese nombre son String, gráficamente no va a representar nada